# Customize Firebase custom key from push() method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the alternative for `push()` when adding data to list in Firebase Real-time database? I want to use my own custom key instead of the key generated. I am trying to add new username to `users` list in my database anytime a new user signs up.

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(username);


                            databaseReference.child("users").setValue(userInformation);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Users.class));
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Push IDs are a non-magical, well [documented](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) way to generate statistically guaranteed to be unique keys.

If you instead want to use your own IDs, use `child()` instead:

```
ref.child("myOwnId").setValue(...);
```

#### Update

Typically you want to store the users under their uid:

```
UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(username); 
String uid = task.getUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference userRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(uid);
userRef.setValue(userInformation);
```

Comment: Please this method keeps replacing the values at the reference rather than adding to the list. Any help? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Calling `setValue()` will replace the existing value. If you don't want that, you want to call `updateChildren()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields. Note that it is a lot easier to efficiently help if your question includes the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](;http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv) you're struggling with.

Comment: Please i just added my code same @Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 0):

> This is the "Custom id" i wanted to add

```
     String srolls = rollno.getText().toString();

      reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student").child(srolls);
```

created a hash map to store the data ...

```
            HashMap<String ,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("fname",fname.getText().toString()); //taking from edit text
            map.put("lname",lname.getText().toString());//taken from edit text
            map.put("mac",mac.getText().toString()); //taken from edit text
            reff.setValue(map); //setting the text value in the database
```

> Output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcarm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can first push your key and then set value to it.

```
databaseReference.child("users").child("custom_key").push();
databaseReference.child("users").child("custom_key").setValue(userInformation);
```